# How can I get the percentage of random variates in an interval? (Python)

Tags: python, math, random, intervals

let's say I generate 10000 normally distributed random variates with σ = 1 and μ = 0:

```
from scipy.stats import norm

x = norm.rvs(size=10000,loc=0,scale=1)
```

How can I get the percentage of random variates in [-1,1] or [-3,3]? How can I count the percentage that will fall into these intervals?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking how to calculate the percentage of pre-calculated values which fall into these ranges or the statistical calculation of expected percentage of values which fall into this range?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
import numpy as np
print(sum(np.abs(x)<1) / len(x) * 100)
```

`sum(np.abs(x)<1)` finds the number of samples in the (-1, 1) range and dividing that by the number of samples, you get what you need.

Edit: You can replace `np.abs(x)<1` with `(x<1) & (-1<x)` to make it work for non-symmetric ranges and also make it work without `numpy`.